# Calling dialog api opens a browser when using Word inside Microsoft Teams

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams on Mac (maybe also on other versions) you have the possibility to edit a document inside Teams. This will open an instance of Word Online.

We have a Office web add-in that utilizes the dialog API to login in to our service. We open this by calling `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(_UrlGoesHere_)`. However, when inside Teams, this method will not open a dialog, but instead use the behavior of Word Online (as if you were in a browser) and launch a completely new browser window.

This means that we lose the connection between the addIn and the login dialog because the browser window is no longer a child of the web add-in taskpane and it's therefore not possible to make any callbacks to the addIn.

This seems like a misbehaviour in Word/web add-ins? Or should this be done differently when inside Teams?

Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look at [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview) in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: The problem is that we don't have a Teams integration (and don't intend to in the near future). 
We have a Web Add-in in Word which Microsoft has made available inside of Teams. But when using the Web Add-in in Word inside of Teams the Dialog Api of Office.js is misbehaving. This is therefore more likely a problem in Office.js rather than in Teams since Office.js is wrongly detecting that it has been opened from a browser.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing the behavior of Word Online is that you're *using Word Online*. When you're editing a document in Microsoft Teams, you're simply using Word Online within an IFrame.

Keep in mind that the native Microsoft Teams client is still effectively a web app. Teams is built on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) which itself is built on [Chromium and Node.js](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/about#about-electron).

You could try using the [`displayInIframe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=office-js#displayiniframe) option of the Dialog API. Enabling this option will result in the dialog being displayed in an `IFrame` overlaying the editor rather than opening a new browser window. I'm not set up to confirm this will work when Word Online is embedded within and `IFrame` in Teams but it is certainly worth testing:

```
displayDialogAsync('url', {displayInIframe: true}): void;
```

Comment: Marc is correct, but @Oskar-Konstantyner - does your add-in work in Word Online?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly in Word Online (opens a window and communicates back to the Addin).
I will try with the `displayInIFrame` work-around

Comment: Actually it did not work with displayInIframe, since what we are showing in the Office dialog are authentication pages that do not allow to be opened in iFrames (for instance AzureAD login - as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#take-advantage-of-a-performance-option-in-office-online).
I guess because of that there are no work-arounds beside from developing a Microsoft Teams app ourselves.

Comment: What I'm about to suggest is a bit of a long shot so please don't think less of me if it fails spectacularly (altough I'll take all the credit if it works :-) ).  If you're using AAD, you might be able to get away with just using the Word API's SSO functionality. Basically, this allows you to grab a token for Microsoft Graph using the current Word Online account. Since there isn't a popup involved, it might "just work". Take a look at this page for details: https://aka.ms/OFS_SSO

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT We also got information from a client trying to use our add-in in Office Online within Teams, but due to Office Online not using the Teams dialog, they get redirected to the browser, and that can't send them back. (We do have checks for if they user is in Teams, and if so, send through the Teams Javascript API, but that doesn't seem to be working in Office online either